# Binding.scala - SBT Out Of Memory issues

Tags: scala.js, binding.scala

I have a large `@html` function (125 lines) and after that sbt fails with OutOfMemory. I increased sbt's memory to 8g and same thing so it's not just it needed a little more memory.
Is this a known issue with Binding.scala?

- sbt 1.3.2
- scala 2.13.3
- JDK11
- scala js 1.1.1
- "org.lrng.binding"             %%% "html"      % "1.0.3"
- "com.thoughtworks.binding"     %%% "binding"   % "12.0.0"

```
  @html def topNav: NodeBinding[Node] = {
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand bg-white shadow mb-4 topbar static-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3" id="sidebarToggleTop" type="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
        <form class="form-inline d-none d-sm-inline-block mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="bg-light form-control border-0 small" type="text" placeholder="Search for ..."/>
            <div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-primary py-0" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button></div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-nowrap ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown d-sm-none no-arrow">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3 animated--grow-in" role="menu" aria-labelledby="searchDropdown">
              <form class="form-inline mr-auto navbar-search w-100">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input class="bg-light form-control border-0 small" type="text" placeholder="Search for ..."/>
                  <div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-primary py-0" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button></div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1" data:role="presentation">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">3+</span><i class="fas fa-bell fa-fw"></i></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-list dropdown-menu-right animated--grow-in"
                   role="menu">
                <h6 class="dropdown-header">alerts center</h6>
                <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <div class="mr-3">
                    <div class="bg-primary icon-circle"><i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i></div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <span class="small text-gray-500">December 12, 2019</span>
                    <p>A new monthly report is ready to download!</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <div class="mr-3">
                    <div class="bg-success icon-circle"><i class="fas fa-donate text-white"></i></div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <span class="small text-gray-500">December 7, 2019</span>
                    <p>$290.29 has been deposited into your account!</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <div class="mr-3">
                    <div class="bg-warning icon-circle"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-white"></i></div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <span class="small text-gray-500">December 2, 2019</span>
                    <p>Spending Alert: We've noticed unusually high spending for your account.</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="text-center dropdown-item small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1" data:role="presentation">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i><span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">7</span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-list dropdown-menu-right animated--grow-in"
                   role="menu">
                <h6 class="dropdown-header">alerts center</h6>
                <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                    <img class="rounded-circle" src="assets/img/avatars/avatar4.jpeg"/>
                    <div class="bg-success status-indicator"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="font-weight-bold">
                    <div class="text-truncate"><span>Hi there! I am wondering if you can help me with a problem I've been having.</span></div>
                    <p class="small text-gray-500 mb-0">Emily Fowler - 58m</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                    <img class="rounded-circle" src="assets/img/avatars/avatar2.jpeg"/>
                    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="font-weight-bold">
                    <div class="text-truncate"><span>I have the photos that you ordered last month!</span></div>
                    <p class="small text-gray-500 mb-0">Jae Chun - 1d</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                    <img class="rounded-circle" src="assets/img/avatars/avatar3.jpeg"/>
                    <div class="bg-warning status-indicator"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="font-weight-bold">
                    <div class="text-truncate"><span>Last month's report looks great, I am very happy with the progress so far, keep up the good work!</span></div>
                    <p class="small text-gray-500 mb-0">Morgan Alvarez - 2d</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="d-flex align-items-center dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                    <img class="rounded-circle" src="assets/img/avatars/avatar5.jpeg"/>
                    <div class="bg-success status-indicator"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="font-weight-bold">
                    <div class="text-truncate"><span>Am I a good boy? The reason I ask is because someone told me that people say this to all dogs, even if they aren't good...</span></div>
                    <p class="small text-gray-500 mb-0">Chicken the Dog · 2w</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="text-center dropdown-item small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <div class="shadow dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown"></div>
          </li>
          <div class="d-none d-sm-block topbar-divider"></div>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow" data:role="presentation">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><span class="d-none d-lg-inline mr-2 text-gray-600 small">Valerie Luna</span><img class="border rounded-circle img-profile" src="assets/img/avatars/avatar1.jpeg"/></a>
              <div
              class="dropdown-menu shadow dropdown-menu-right animated--grow-in" role="menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" data:role="presentation" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Profile</a><a class="dropdown-item" data:role="presentation" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Settings</a>
                <a
                class="dropdown-item" data:role="presentation" href="#"><i class="fas fa-list fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Activity log</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" data:role="presentation" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your error messages?